# Fully functional package manager for MacOS

Tags: macos, homebrew, software-update

**Intro**

I am a big fun of Linux. I am going to change my job and will be forced to use MacOS. I know I need to get used to many new things and admit "MacOS way and philosophy" in general. Also I know it is better to agree to some things than try to change them.

**Problem**

I do care about security and stability and this is why I prefer to update all my system once a week. On Linux I can do it with one command only `apt upgrade` which updates the system and all installed apps as well.

On MacOS I use homebrew package manager which doesn't allow to update system and GUI apps (actually it does, but it is remove & install, which caused data and privileges lose). This is why on Mondays I have to run every single app and check for updates via internal update mechanism. Furthermore, if an app gets an update, it notifies me about this and it is impossible to turn off such notifications, which will be shown until the app is updated.

I can't bare such behavior and every Monday it makes me sad. I can't believe there isn't an opportunity to update all apps with a single command. And, for example, chrome may get a new update next day and I have to look at this "New update available" icon all the week long ))

**Question**

Is there a package manager which allows to keep my system updated with minimum routine from my side?

Comment: Yes apple's software update and appstore

Comment: https://www.corecode.io/macupdater/

Comment: According MacUpdater FAQ, the answer to the question: *"Can MacUpdater update apps downloaded from the 'Mac App Store'?"* is *"No. Apps downloaded from the 'Mac App Store' need to be updated by the 'Mac App Store' app."*. So this product does not update *"the system and all installed apps as well"* which was stated by the OP.

Comment: it is ok to update system and apps separately. If I could update all apps by only one button it would be way better compare to homebrew flow! So, MacUpdater looks pretty good to me.

Comment: but I can't find such apps as tig, ngrok, htop, etc, which are must have for me

Comment: looks like I need to use thee mechanisms: apple's software update for system update, MacUpdate fro GUI apps management and homebrew for CLI apps. Sounds a bit over complicated...

Comment: you could have a script or cronjob that calls `softwareupdate` for macos updates and `brew` for CLI apps

Comment: is it possible to run MacUpdater from the terminal in order to update all apps which have updates?

Comment: I don't believe you can get MacUpdater to auto update from Terminal. But you can leave it running all the time (with a menubar icon) and set it to do regular scans. See my second edit in my answer.

Comment: > which caused data ... loss
Homebrew should not cause this when upgrading apps. Data is not stored in application bundles.

Comment: If an application stores user data within the .app folder it will be lost after update. I have to admin it is quite rare case, but it exists.

Comment: Write access to the `.app` isn't granted to all user accounts - sometimes including the administrator account, so that application would already be broken

Comment: The point was that we aren't expect that some data still exists after an application was deleted. This is why `--greedy` parameter doesn't work for all cases. Sometime data may be lost. And every time after such procedure you have to grant privileges back.

Answer (score 2):

`apt upgrade` on Linux only updates apps installed through `apt`.

Therefore on macOS you need to run a command to update software installed through each source you obtained the software.

You could obtain all your software through Homebrew, which includes Google Chrome. Then `brew upgrade` would upgrade Chrome too.

Comment: Homebrew Cask by default won't automatically update apps with built-in update function. I can fix it by using `greedy` param:
```
--greedy
       Also include casks with auto_updates true or version :latest.
```
but in this case it works as `remove + install` which causes many problems (data and permissions loss)

Answer (score 0):

As it was suggested in comments to the original post you can use softwareupdate for mac app store updates, brew upgrade for apps installed via homebrew and as "a big fan of linux" you should be familiar (or at least not afraid of scripting), so try using MacOS's built-in Automator application where you should be able to script workflow needed for making macupdater to update apps. And then in a good tradition of unix philosophy you can combine all those 3 together and get working solution.

Comment: Do you have such solution? Are you interested in it? I wonder how come the most basic thing in any OS is in such terrible condition? Or, maybe, all mac-users are big fans of manual updates?

Comment: MacOS is the second most popular OS in the world! It should be a mistake from my side! I can't believe that such basic thing works this bad.

Answer (score 0):

[MacUpdater](https://www.corecode.io/macupdater/) is the best app for checking your GUI apps and installing updates. It will take your weekly update regimen from a chore to a pleasure.

It is a 99.9% (my estimate) complete solution for alerting you to updates, including those in the Mac App Store. Wherever possible MacUpdate has a single click to update an app, and in other cases leads you to getting the update. And, so there are no nasty surprises, alerts you to major changes of app version number which may indicate a paid update.

Here the main window of MacUpdater on my Mac:
[image]
Regarding timing, MacUpdater can be set to do regular background checks for updates if you want. But it is easy to run it once a week.

What is missing from MacUpdater is alerting for command line apps installed by Homebrew. So you still need `brew update` and `brew upgrade` to check and install those updates.

Note, I have nothing to do with the developer - I am just a happy (and paying) user.

Edit (some additional notes):

There are three types of apps which can't be updated automatically.  Firstly, those that are not yet able to be updated automatically (and maybe never be). After clicking 'Manual Update' this windows is shown:
[image: Manual Update]

Secondly there are a few apps (in my case those by Adobe and Marcel Bresink) which have their own updater app. The best that can be done here is to open the app specific updater. For Photoshop, clicking the 'Open Updater' button loads Adobe's Creative Cloud app.

And finally, Mac App Store apps. For these MacUpdater opens the App Store with the app to be updated.  In my part of the world, MacUpdater detects the presence of updates many days before the 'Updates' button in the App Store app's sidebar.

Another Edit regarding automation:

MacUpdater can be configured to run all the time in the background with regular scans of your apps. Clicking on the menubar icon produces this:
[image: Menubar]

Whilst I like to check each app before updating, there are options to make this easier.  Everyone need to explore these, but here is one of the panes in MacUpdater's settings:

[image: Settings]

Comment: so far it looks like the best solution to me. but I still have to use not one, but three update managers: appstore, MacUpdater and brew. Not perfect but at least something...

Comment: What do `Open Updater` and `Manual Update` mean?

Comment: @GHopper I have added some comments about Open Updater, etc.  For me, MacUpdater really has revolutionised the updating process. It's alerting is now (after a few years) highly accurate. And today, the alert about App Cleaner and Uninstaller did indeed lead to a paid update - a good warning. You won't do better than MacUpdater + brew + App Store.